# How to export unit test results/stack trace from Resharper

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, resharper

I have quite a lengthy test session which has detailed output in the Resharper test runner. How could I export the "execution log/stack trace" shown in the right window for all tests.

I think this should be quite simple, since these results must be saved somewhere since they survive visual studio restarts/computer reboots.
So accessing the raw files is fine for me.

Thnx in advance for some insights.

Kind regards,
Dwight

Answer (score 0):

You just have to run all your unit tests with Resharper.

Open Visual Studio -> In menu, choose Resharper -> Unit Tests -> "Run All Tests From Solution".

This will open a new window that runs all your tests.

In this window, you have a little square with an arrow pointing upwards to the right to the left of "Options". Here you can choose to export to different formats.

Comment: Hej, that only exports the tree and not the execution log/stack trace

Comment: ah, ok I then I misunderstood what you where after

Comment: Well I found the results in some (un)usable format in the %USER%\AppData\local\JetBrains\Transient\ReSharperPlatformVs14\v06\SolutionCaches\_%SLN-NAME%.633387306.00\Db, but it feels so hackish...