# View previous runs' stack traces (or possibly export them) from Resharper?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, jetbrains-ide

I recently discovered Resharper's Stack Trace explorer, which I was immediately grateful for. It makes reading and navigating them so much easier for me than in the years before I knew about it.

However, I'm confused about when they're "saved" between sessions and when they're not. For example, recently when debugging a C# Azure Function app, I had an exception trace visible in the Stack Trace Explorer. When I stopped debugging, the trace disappeared. Whenever I started debugging again, it reappeared. However, since then, I've been unable to reproduce this behavior. They only appear sometimes in the explorer, and after stopping debugging, they're gone and do not reappear on the next session.

I've found a old [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953866/how-to-export-unit-test-results-stack-trace-from-resharper) that didn't get much attention, but it was focused mainly on exporting them (and 7 years have passed, so things may be different now.) I'm fairly okay with either solution—either having the previous traces saved within the IDE as it seemed to do for me previously, or exporting them in a way that they can be re-imported into the stack trace explorer later. I've read through Resharper's documentation on it and I'm not sure that they can actually be exported. However, I couldn't find anything that addressed the "preserved between runs" behavior. Any information is much appreciated!

Comment: What you describe does not match how Stack Trace Explorer should work (even according to the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Navigation_and_Search__Navigating_to_Exception.html)). You can create a tab with a stack trace using the "Browse Stack Trace" command, or R# will automatically open a stack trace when it detects that the clipboard contains one. The tabs should stay open until you close them manually.